# Android - proguard.cfg error

Tags: android, proguard

I imported an older project after a I installed the android SDK on a new computer. I am getting the following error in the "problems" window in eclipse.

```
Obsolete proguard file; use -keepclasseswithmembers instead of -keepclasseswithmembernames  proguard.cfg    /MyApplication  line 1
```

Here is the file. I tried replacing the `-keepclasseswithmembernames`in this file with `-keepclasseswithmembers`but it did not help.

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
```

Comment: What proguard version are you using? `java -jar android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sample config file that I use with proguard 4.4, JDK 1.6, target android 2.1.
Check your proguard version by double clicking on the jar file or with `java -jar android-sdk/tools/proguard/lib/proguard.jar` (use android sdk install path)

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

Comment: I am using version 4.4 . I will give your sample code a try. Thanks

Comment: I get an error: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error code 1. When using the above code.

Comment: OK, that looks much better, even though there's still an error. Can you try solving that using some of the suggestions found on the first couple of links on google? All are SO link. https://www.google.com/search?ix=heb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Conversion+to+Dalvik+format+failed+with+error+code+1

Comment: I got it working with the first link. Updated proguard to 4.6. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an Eclipse / Android SDK error 
i suggest

1) close the project is giving error to you
2) remove it from eclipse ( do not remove folder or source )
3) import the project you removed
4) clean and build again

Best regards
stefano

Comment: in my case this did not work (neither does the copy method you also suggest).  i had "upgraded" (changed?) from JavaEE Indigo + ADTetc to the latest ADT bundle (v21.0.0-531062 with eclipse 3.7.2) running with JDK1.7 under windowsxp.  thanx for the effort, might help others in similar, yet slightly different circumstances and who also run into this symptom.

Answer (score 1):

if [Previous answer didnt help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8666562/232727)

Then just create empty Android project in Eclipse and copy/replace created "proguard.cfg" file to your project.

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me; Right click on project's name, and click on "Android Project". Then select "Clear Lint Markers". Seems that I had accidentally run "Lint" for checking for some common problems after which I began seeing those proguard.cfg errors. Funny thing is that even though I was compiling in debug mode, eclipse would still complain about proguard (which is supposed to be used when compiling in release mode only).

Comment: did not work for me (system specs are in my comment to stefano in this post).

Answer (score 0):

proguard.cfg will be in your project's root.  edit it, replacing:

```
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
```

with

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
```

worked for me running ADT bundle (v21.0.0-531062 with eclipse 3.7.2 using JDK1.7 under windowsxp).

Answer (score 0):

selected the error in eclipse problems window. and it works for me.