# Proguard Error / Dalvik Error 1 When Signing Android App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

Before I start, wanted to say hi and thanks for reading this, I've had this problem for quite a bit and any help is appreciated!

I've been working on this project for some good time, and it has been testing perfectly fine. I could run it and it works on my android tablet, no errors or anything. But when I finally tried to release it and go into "Android Tools -> Export Signed Application", I was returned with **Dalvik Error 1**.

I tried enabling proguard, and was left with a lot of unreferenced classes. Such as:

```
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Note: there were 439 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.EJBHome: can't find superclass or interface java.rmi.Remote
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.EJBObject: can't find superclass or interface java.rmi.Remote
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find superclass or interface javax.management.DynamicMBean
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient extends or implements program class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class javax.xml.validation.ValidatorHandler extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.ContentHandler
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xml.sax.ext.Attributes2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.Attributes
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xml.sax.ext.Attributes2Impl extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.helpers.AttributesImpl
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.ext.LexicalHandler
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xml.sax.ext.DefaultHandler2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.ext.DeclHandler
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xml.sax.ext.EntityResolver2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.EntityResolver
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xml.sax.ext.Locator2 extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.Locator
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xml.sax.ext.Locator2Impl extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.helpers.LocatorImpl
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.Locator
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.XMLReader
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: library class org.xmlpull.v1.sax2.Driver extends or implements program class org.xml.sax.Attributes
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: Mxl.YoutubeChannel: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.String getTextContent()' in class org.w3c.dom.Node
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: com.sun.tools.xjc.Version: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Version
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: com.sun.tools.xjc.Version: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Version
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.EJBContext: can't find referenced class javax.transaction.UserTransaction
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.EJBHome: can't find referenced class java.rmi.Remote
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.EJBHome: can't find referenced class java.rmi.RemoteException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.EJBObject: can't find referenced class java.rmi.Remote
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.EJBObject: can't find referenced class java.rmi.RemoteException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.EntityBean: can't find referenced class java.rmi.RemoteException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.Handle: can't find referenced class java.rmi.RemoteException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.HomeHandle: can't find referenced class java.rmi.RemoteException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.SessionBean: can't find referenced class java.rmi.RemoteException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: javax.ejb.SessionSynchronization: can't find referenced class java.rmi.RemoteException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.IdleConnectionHandler: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.IdleConnectionHandler: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.InMemoryDnsResolver: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.InMemoryDnsResolver: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RouteSpecificPool: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RouteSpecificPool: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.ObjectName
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanServer
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanRegistrationException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor: can't find referenced class javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.examples.oauth.GetAccessToken: can't find referenced class java.awt.Desktop
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.examples.oauth.GetAccessToken: can't find referenced class java.awt.Desktop
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.examples.oauth.GetAccessToken: can't find referenced class java.awt.Desktop
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.CommonsLoggingLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Level
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.Log4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.apache.log4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLogger: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.Logger
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.internal.logging.SLF4JLoggerFactory: can't find referenced class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanConstructorInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanOperationInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanParameterInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanConstructorInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanOperationInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeDataSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeNotFoundException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.ReflectionException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.ReflectionException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.DynamicMBean
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.InvalidAttributeValueException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.SimpleType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularType
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanInfo
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanAttributeInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanConstructorInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanOperationInfoSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.MBeanNotificationInfo
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenMBeanParameterInfo
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.openmbean.TabularDataSupport
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.Attribute
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: twitter4j.management.APIStatisticsOpenMBean: can't find referenced class javax.management.AttributeList
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: there were 309 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: there were 13 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]          You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]          be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]          You may need to recompile the code or update the library versions.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:330)
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:212)
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:87)
[2013-05-14 15:40:24 - MxlTestApp]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:484)
```

Although I'd like to say these shouldn't exist, I do have the libraries that I would believe have these classes that are "unreferenced". Though if anyone knows where these classes are and could tell me, I'd like that. Though I'm confused on why this also is an issue since again, this application has worked well before I had to release it, which is always on my mind.

I have this project with the current libraries being used, perhaps this will give away any clues:

- Facebook SDK
- Twitter4j
- ZXing Scanne Activity

I've tried disabling proguard, which gives me just a Dalvik Error. I've tried enabling it, giving me this error above. My Proguard is up to date, it's at 4.9 currently. I've tried adding some things to the proguard such as "ignore jaxax*". Which did let it finally build, but that apps crashed at start up with the same error as above unfortunately.

Some more information if needed, my android developer tools is currently
Build: v21.1.0-569685

And my tablet that's been running these tests is a nice little Nexus 7.

That's about all I know of that I can throw at everyone. Again, thanks a lot for reading all this, I appreciate that alone. And any help recommended will also be heavily appreciated!

Comment: First thing to check would to make sure you have the libraries checked in the Order and Export tab of your Java Build Path for the project. There is a big difference in the build process when you are exporting an application and simply debugging it. One of the big differences is progaurd runs and strips out everything it can and obfuscates your code.

Comment: Which proguard version are you using?

Comment: @Jyro117 Got my hopes up because the libraries weren't checked in the export tab. Did it but unfortunately no success, get the same error. I have those checked, and the jar files are in the libs folder of my project if that shines any light.

Comment: @Trinimon it's proguard 4.9

Comment: Can you post your proguard configuration you are using? It would probably help with debugging this.

Comment: @Jyro117 Here's the proguard config currently: http://pastebin.com/CdQ0McWj

Comment: I believe part of the issue you are having is the libraries are using javax.rmi.* which isn't part of Android. Why it works in debug confuses me, but I've seen many strange errors when trying to deploy an Android app I am not surprised. I noticed you are missing a few things in your proguard configuration, look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8650595/android-proguard-cfg-error. However, this probably won't help you with your errors, look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902943/how-to-include-additional-javax-packages-in-android-app-with-eclipse it may help.

Answer (score 0):

If you see warnings about missing classes in Eclipse, you should make sure all libraries are exported, so they are passed to ProGuard and included in the resulting apk.

If you then still get warnings about missing classes, they may not be present on Android, e.g. `java.rmi.Remote`. Apparently, your application doesn't use them anyway, so you can tell ProGuard it's okay:

```
-dontwarn java.rmi.**
```

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: can't find referenced class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass).

Classes like `org.xml.sax.**` are a problem if they are duplicated between the application libraries and the Android runtime. You should remove them from your libraries, since the versions in the Android runtime get precedence anyway.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Warning: library class ... depends on program class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)

Also, you should make sure that your configuration file doesn't contain `-injars` or `-libraryjars` options. The Eclipse build process already automatically specifies all the necessary `-injars`, `-outjars`, and `-libraryjars` for you.

See the ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > [Note: duplicate definition of program/library class](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#duplicateclass)